# What is a valid date time/is the parser broken?

Tags: gmail, schema.org, google-schemas

In the example given the startDate doesn't validate! I've tried bumping it forward a few days, but it was still no good!

[image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":             "schema.org",
      "@type":                "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber":    "IO12345",
      "underName": "John Smith",
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "Event",
        "name":               "Google I/O 2013",
        "startDate":          "2013-05-15T08:30-08:00",
        "location":           "Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103"
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
      BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
      Order for: John Smith<br/>
      Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
      Start time: May 15th 2013 8:00am PST<br/>
      Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
      Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While `google-schemas` is the tag that Google wants for this stuff, the community here seems to have settled on the combination of `schema.org` + `gmail`.  If someone at Google wants the tag to continue to exist, it'll be in their best interest to go back and *add* it to earlier questions... not completely rewrite the tags.

Comment: I'm not fussed either way, it's just that they link to that tag search in their documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, that's a bug in the schema validator tool, we'll fix it as soon as possible.

I also checked your markup and you should add the seconds to the `startDate` field, as in "2013-05-15T08:30:00-08:00".

Datetimes should be defined in the markup using the ISO 8601 format:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601